# move_file_uploaded permission denied on chmod 777 directory?

Tags: php

I can't seem to get uploads to work, so I changed the upload directory to be the log directory.  Note that the logs are being successfully written to, but I still cannot upload a file into that directory.

ls -lh

```
drwxrwxr--  2 <user> http 216 Aug  2 10:19 logs
```

I've checked the path by copying it directly from the error message, pasting it into the terminal, and cd'ing to it.  It's an absolute path name.

I've done a whoami on the script and it's reported back as http.

This is in a virtualhost directory using Apache with mod_php.  PHP version 5.4.4, using Arch Linux.

Any ideas?  I'm completely at a loss as to what I should check next.  I even did a touch  to create the file first, and I'm still getting the error.

I should also mention that the parent directory has the sticky bit set for the group.  I don't know if that would affect anything or not.

Here's the actual error message:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(!!snip!!): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>!!snip!!</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYSMakQ' to '!!snip!!' in <b>!!snip!!</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
```

Comment: @MarcB Well actually, it's a 0774. But that's not really the relevant point here (unless the Apache doesn't actually own the directory). @OP: I presume you're actually using `move_uploaded_file()` and not `move_file_uploaded()` in your script?

Comment: More importantly, what's the error you're seeing on file upload?

Comment: Whoops, right, it is 774 - missed the trailing r. I'll just go crawl into a corner over there -->

Comment: It's 774 now, but the point is that I can't get it working even with 777.  And you're right, the function in question was move_uploaded_file, sorry, I was in a hurry.  I've edited the question to include the error message, although I don't believe it's going to be useful in this case.

Comment: Silly question, but is your destination a file in the logs dir, and not the logs dir itself?  Also, is that your apache logs dir or a php logs dir?  you might need to check into the [`open_basedir` setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: It's just a directory we're throwing some custom logs into, nothing to do with apache or PHP error_log.  The directory itself is currently sitting under the site root directory, so it's definitely not experiencing open_basedir restrictions.